# Android - queryPurchase() returns an empty list but I purchased an in app product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing, android-billing, google-play-billing

I have implemented in app products in my app. I can make successful purchase and everything works fine. But in one device, purchase doesn't work although when I try to make a purchase again, I get the response "Product already owned" which shows that the purchase is fine. But queryPurchase() returns an empty purchase list.
I've only one email on that device.

```
public void queryPurchase() {
    Runnable queryPurchaseRequest = getQueryPurchaseRequest();
    executeRequest(queryPurchaseRequest);
}

    private Runnable getQueryPurchaseRequest() {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                if(purchasesResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    ArrayList<Purchase> purchaseList = new ArrayList<>();
                    purchaseList.addAll(purchasesResult.getPurchasesList());
    
                    if(isSubscriptionSupported()) {
                        Purchase.PurchasesResult subscriptionResult
                                = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
    
                        if (subscriptionResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                            purchaseList.addAll(subscriptionResult.getPurchasesList());
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Got an error response trying to query subscription purchases");
                        }
                    }
                    onQueryPurchasesFinished(purchaseList);
                } else {
                    Utilities.setPurchaseLog("onBilling manager on query purchase request: result unknown\n");
    
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Note: Billing result, subscription response code everything seems successful. And everything is working perfectly on other devices.

Have anyone any solution? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you ever tried to clean Play cache and call queryPurchases again? Or did you set the in-app item as "non-consumable"? If not, did you encounter the issue on the same device on which you purchased the item?

Comment: Yes I've cleaned Play cache & query purchase multiple times. No, in-app item isn't set non consumable. Yes, I've encountered the issue on same device on which I purchased.

Comment: Same happening over here. Everything implemented as per developer guide. even published the app in the internal test channel and installed from Play Store. When I call querySkuDetails to try to subscribe again it comes back with item already owned result. In the query purchases(SUBS) the list comes back empty

Comment: Any update for this?

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug that has been happening for ages now, since billing libraries version 2.x (Priority: P1 , Severity S2)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160473001

I think the best thing you can do is going there and leaving your star/comment to try to speed things up.

**However**, there's something we can miss sometimes: It turns out that you need to wait for the billingClient.startConnection() call to finish doing it's thing and onBillingSetupFinished() callback gets called on the provided BillingClientStateListener. Only after that you can call the queryPurchases method. If you call queryPurchases beforee finishing the connection to the service, you will get an empty list.

Comment: I get access denied when I click on that link

Comment: I'm getting access denied too, Maybe the link was deleted. Nonetheless the "However" Section is the most usual situation when this problem arises.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer to this same question via
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782353/android-play-billing-library-onskudetailsresponse-responsecode-is-0-but-the-si)

I had to comment out the debug suffix in the .app build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        // applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }
}
```